# PHP : Associative array indexing issue

Tags: php, arrays

My problem is very specific. I'm a beginner php programmer and I'm having difficulty indexing the array datastructure in PHP. The program is reading from an input file (`input.txt`) and storing the result into an array with key same as the item. Although the `input.txt` files have numbers for convenience I have to store them as string ( My program needs integers of size greater than 32 bit). But when I try to index them as `$a["3"]` I get an error `Undefined offset: 3`. I `tried $a['3']`, `$a[3]` all with the same result. But curiously I am able to index last element in the array that is `$a["2"]` correctly! Please help.

Here is the input text file :

```
3
4
5
1
2
```

Here is the code segment :

```
<?php
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);
    $temp=0;
    $a= array();
    $file= fopen("input.txt","r") or exit( "unable to open file");
    while(!feof($file)){
        $temp=fgets($file); 
        $a[$temp]=$temp;     
    }   
    fclose($file);
    echo "<br>The array is .. ";
    foreach ($a as $key => $item) {
        echo "<br> Key => item =",$key."=>",$item ;
        echo "<br>Manual array test ",$a["3"]; // This line demonstrates the problem. 
    }
    echo "<br>Manual array test ",$a["2"]; // This one has no error! So basically only the last element is being indexed correctly

    //echo "<br> No of 2 sums is ",twoSum($a,4,6);
?>
```

Comment: `$temp=(int)fgets($file);`, no?

Comment: you should get syntax errors for using `,` where you should use `.` when you concat strings. For example here: `echo "<br> Key => item =",$key."=>",$item ;` it should be `echo "<br> Key => item =".$key."=>".$item ;`

Comment: @raina77ow OP wants to store integers > INT_MAX, so needs to use string type.

Comment: @AndreschSerj `,` also works in `echo` https://eval.in/143690

Comment: @AndreschSerj No, actually echo can take multiple arguments, so `echo "a","b";` is correct, and will behave the same as `echo "a"."b";`

Comment: @Benubird Never seen before. Weird. Thank you for pointing that out thou.

Comment: @JeevanB.Manoj since Manoj's Answer solved your Problem, consider accepting the answer so this question is marked as solved and doesn't get any more unneccessary attention. Also it shows appreciation.

Answer (score 3):

New line value is also getting stored in `$temp`, `trim` the `$temp` data as below and try

```
$temp = trim(fgets($file));
```